# Issues to implement video player with fotoramajs

Tags: jwplayer, fotorama

Facing some issues to implement video player(jw,HTML 5) with fotorama .Any video players are implemented  with this library ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you tried to embed this the JW player?

Comment: Ethan,Thanks a lot  for the reply ,the work is in local machine and  For time being I implemented the same using iframe  .

Comment: Ok, if you can put something up I will be able to debug.

Comment: Ethan thanks and I managed the issue using Iframe.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507369/fotorama-custom-video/18509788#18509788