# Fotorama custom video

Tags: javascript, fotorama

is it possible to have custom video on fotorama, I can't embed my video to youtube, vimeo or any other video services, I need to have a simple video tag to display the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: http://fotorama.io/customize/html/
So you can use the HTML5 video tag or any custom video flash pleer.

Comment: Thanks.Yes, that was exactly my question how to use an html5 video tag to display video, the documentation is only talking about using iframe

Answer (score 0):

Built-in support for YouTube and Vimeo:
http://fotorama.io/customize/video/

You can also add any video if you have iframe link and previews. Here are the Dailymotion videos:
http://fotorama.io/examples/video-custom.html

Fotorama can show video in iframe. So you have to create separate page with autoplaying video stretched full-page (width & height 100%). And then link to this page in fotorama:

```
<div class="fotorama">
    <a href="/link/to/the/video" data-video="true" data-img="preview.jpg"><img src="preview_small.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Live demo:
http://artpolikarpov.github.io/fotorama/test/video-flowplayer.html

And three separate videos from this example:
http://artpolikarpov.github.io/fotorama/test/flowplayer/1.html
http://artpolikarpov.github.io/fotorama/test/flowplayer/2.html
http://artpolikarpov.github.io/fotorama/test/flowplayer/3.html

Answer (score 0):

IF you are inserting into a post:

```
[gallery ids= 750,749,748,747,746,745,744,743,742,741" width="100%" ratio="1024/768" autoplay="3000" stopautoplayontouch="false" loop="true" transition="slide" keyboard="true"]
```

OR

```
<div class="fotorama" data-width="100%" data-ratio="1024/768" data-autoplay="3000" data-stopautoplayontouch="false" data-loop="true" data-transition="slide" data-keyboard="true">
<a href="youtube link">jets</a>

<img src="image url" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-745" />

<img src="image url" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-743" />

<img src="image url" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-741" /></a>
</div>
```